# Sound on file save when using Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js

I've created project with Vue CLI. Every time i save ***.vue** file i hear sound of Windows message, but i see changes in browser. There is no error. This sound is annoying! Can I remove it?

**[UPDATE]**
Here is my code:

***App.vue***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p v-html="msg"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      msg: "Some message."
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete I've edited question.